# Hibernate: sorting with Join

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two tables: `resumeId` and `CandidateInfo`.

```
String sql_query = "from shared.SelectedResumes as sr " +
                   "join sr.resumeId as cri " +

// 1st statement  
if (sortField.equals("resumeText")) {
    sql_query = sql_query + "order by cri.resumeText " + sortDirection;
}
// 2nd statement
else if(sortField.equals("cities")) {
    sql_query = sql_query + "order by ci.candidateInfo.cities " + sortDirection;
}
```

My 1st statement is running fine, but the 2nd statement is not working because `cities` is not in `ci` (i.e `resumeId`) its in the `CandidateInfo` (which is joined with `resumeId`).

How can I access `cities` from `resumeId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
from shared.SelectedResumes as sr join sr.resumeId as cri join cri.candidateInfo as ci
```